Why I have Uncaught Snapshot missing on Livewire component error with internal component?
In laravel 11 / livewire 3.5 app I have ContactUsFeedbackModal defined as :
namespace App\Livewire\Admin;

use LivewireUI\Modal\ModalComponent;
use App\Models\ContactUs;

class ContactUsFeedbackModal extends ModalComponent
{
    public ContactUsFeedbackForm $form;
    use AppCommonTrait;
    public $contactUs;

    public function mount(ContactUs $contactUs)
    {
        $this->contactUs = $contactUs;
        $this->form->setContactUs($this->contactUs);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.contact-us.contact-us-feedback-modal');
    }

and inside view of the componewnt resources/views/livewire/admin/contact-us/contact-us-feedback-modal.blade.php I have

another component defined as :
   <div wire:key="prefix_{{ $form->id }}" class="d1">

       <livewire:admin.common.assign-staff-users selectSupervisor="true" :key="'wrapperAssignStaffUsers-' . $form->id"  />

   </div>

and I got error :
Uncaught Snapshot missing on Livewire component with id: JlIOFevl4rtGmAdQP9ke

That is not a loop actually : just componewnt admin.common.assign-staff-users is used 1 time
Component AssignStaffUsers is defined as(not sure doews it matter ?) :
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Admin\Common;

use App\Library\StaffUsers;
use App\Library\SupervisorUsers;
use Livewire\Component;

class AssignStaffUsers extends Component
{
    public bool $selectSupervisor;
    public $staffUsersSelectionItems = [];
    public $supervisorUsersSelectionItems = [];
    public $selectedStaffUsers = [];
    public $selectedSupervisorUserId = null;

    public function mount( bool $selectSupervisor)
    {
        $this->selectSupervisor = $selectSupervisor;

        $this->staffUsersSelectionItems = StaffUsers::get(true);
        $this->supervisorUsersSelectionItems = SupervisorUsers::get(true);

    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.common.assign-staff-users');
    }

    public function addStaffUser()
    {
        $this->selectedStaffUsers[] = ['staff_user_id' => ''];
    }

    public function removeStaffUser($index)
    {
        unset($this->selectedStaffUsers[$index]);
        array_values($this->selectedStaffUsers);
    }

    public function updated($property, $value)
    {
        $this->dispatch('assignStaffUsersUpdated', $this->selectedStaffUsers);
    }


}

if to commewnt linew with <livewire:admin.common.assign-staff-users  - I have no this error...
what is wrong in my code ?
